# PUT HTTP Request in HTTP API Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, http

I'm unable to use put http requests in WordPress.

https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API

This link says you can do it through `wp_remote_request()`? But where to specify that ?

Can anyone help me with this? I need a code.

Answer (score 8):

```php
$body = array(
            "status" => "publish"
);
$args = array(
    'headers' => array(
    'Content-Type'   => 'application/json',
    ),
    'body'      => json_encode($body),
    'method'    => 'PUT'
);

$result =  wp_remote_request( "http:300/wp-json/wp/post/1", $args );
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```
$response = wp_remote_request( 'http://test.com/test', [
    'method' => 'PUT'
] );
```